# How to use cppunit just like junit --- two mains

Tags: c++, cppunit

I know that the unit test for Java is very simple. We just need use JUnit and run test classes as JUnit test.

Now I'm working with C++ and I find a test library: cppunit.

It seems that I need to run my test with a specific function `main`.
However, a `cpp` project can have ONLY ONE `main`.

What should I do? I have to switch mains when I do my test and when I run my project?

Comment: Funny thing how a Java project can have MORE THAN ONE `main`. Sorry, but it's just a matter of what you're used to. People who have grown up on Java are often surprised to find that other languages aren't the same.

Comment: @PeteBecker  Yeah. Totally. If we use another different language, we will find that our world will change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What should I do? I have to switch mains when I do my test and when I run my project?

You should separate the code to test into a library project, that can be linked from your target application and the unit test runner.

Then have two more projects providing a `main()` function:

- one for the target app, that just forwards `main()` implementation to a call of a `MyTargetApp` class member function, e.g. `MyTargetApp::run()`
- one for the unit testing, that calls a `TestRunner`, and contains all of the test suite and fixture classes (including these for the `MyTargetApp`).

The target application project can be configured without linking against the cppunit library and your test suite/fixture implementations (which will certainly reduce the final artifacts footprint).

---

> However, a cpp project can have ONLY ONE `main`.

Another option is to use just one project with a narrow `main()` function that can be compiled using a conditional preprocessor statement (as from their example on the [`TestRunner` class](http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/cvs/class_test_runner.html)):

```
 #ifdef TESTING
 int runUnitTests(int argc, char* argv[]);
 #endif

 int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

 #ifdef TESTING
     // run the unit tests
     // -----------------------------------------------------------------
     return runUnitTests(argc,argv);
 #else
     // run the application
     // -----------------------------------------------------------------
     MyTargetApp app;
     return app.run(argc,argv);
 #endif
```

---

```
 #ifdef TESTING
 int runUnitTests(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   std::string testPath = (argc > 1) ? std::string(argv[1]) : "";

   // Create the event manager and test controller
   CppUnit::TestResult controller;

   // Add a listener that colllects test result
   CppUnit::TestResultCollector result;
   controller.addListener( &result );        

   // Add a listener that print dots as test run.
   CppUnit::TextTestProgressListener progress;
   controller.addListener( &progress );      

   // Add the top suite to the test runner
   CppUnit::TestRunner runner;
   runner.addTest( CppUnit::TestFactoryRegistry::getRegistry().makeTest() );   
   try {
     std::cout << "Running "  <<  testPath;
     runner.run( controller, testPath );

     std::cerr << std::endl;

     // Print test in a compiler compatible format.
     CppUnit::CompilerOutputter outputter( &result, std::cerr );
     outputter.write();                      
   }
   catch ( std::invalid_argument &e ) {
     // Test path not resolved
     std::cerr  <<  std::endl  
                <<  "ERROR: "  <<  e.what()
                << std::endl;
     return 0;
   }         

   return result.wasSuccessful() ? 0 : 1;
 }
 #endif
```

Then have 2 different project configurations, one that defines `TESTING` and one without.

One disadvantage of this solution is though, you'll get all the unit test suites and fixtures left in your program, because cppunit macros will register and instantiate them automatically, regardless if the will be called from the execution path.

Comment: You mean I create two projects, one is my project and the other is a project that can be linked to my project and to the unit tests? What is a library project?

Comment: @Thomas In fact I meant you should have three projects: 1. A library project that contains all the stuff that should be tested. 2. An application project, that just provides a thin `main()` function and runs your program. 3. A test runner project, that just runs your unit tests. Another option might be to have a single `main()` and place conditionally compiled code using a `#ifdef TESTING` directive, that selects to run your application or to run the unit tests.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. Then it truly is exactly like junit.

Comment: @erip Which one actually ;-)? The 1st suggestion just enforces better re-usability as you should have it with Java modules.

Comment: Your comment about the three projects. :P